# PRISM bootstrapper problem

Tags: wpf, mef, ribbon, bootstrapper, prism-4

I'm starting a PRISM + MEF, WPF application.

In the bootstrapper I'm having some problems. The RootVisual property is not found (silverlight vs wpf?, **what should I use instead for WPF?**) and I see everybody using a UserControl as a shell

```
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
  base.InitializeShell();
  Application.Current.RootVisual = (Shell)this.Shell;
}
```

**How do you set a RibbonWindow as 'rootvisual' (shell) in PRISM (MEF+WPF)?** (I started a Ribbon WPF Application). 
Maybe this is not correct what i'm trying to do but I didn't find any example that uses a RibbonWindow instead of a UserControl as a Shell in PRISM for a WPF application.

I've searched stackoverflow but it could not provide me a clear answer.

Thanks in advance.

edit: indeed it was Window, discovered it a few moments later. "d0h!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = (Shell)this.Shell;
```

And as you can guess `Shell` must be a window.

Comment: "The IModuleCatalog is required and cannot be null in order to initialize the modules."
When doing bootstrapper.Run(); it gives me this message as quoted above.
Do you have to add your own main module to the modulecatalog?

Comment: Check the CreateModuleCatalog method of your bootstrapper. Is it getting called? What does it return?

Comment: I use the ...CreateFromXaml(Uri...) and return this (as seen on the examples).

The xaml file doesn't define any other modules. Should the 'module' where the bootstrapper/shell is in be added to the xaml file?
Should you create just a project that has the shell and bootstrapper and create another project to add the main functionality to that blog or is it ok to have them in the main functionality of the program in the same project which contains the bootstrapper/shell?

Comment: The Shell project is not a module, so it should not be in the list of modules. Usually the shell project doesn't contain any functionality of the application, so it just a shell... The functionality should be in the modules.

Comment: So:
ConfigureAggregateCatalog() does this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));  
and the 
CreateModuleCatalog()
does ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(...)  
I keep on getting that first message (from my first comment) so you cannot just start your shell (mainwindow) without any module if the modulecatalog is empty?